# Duplicate label structure into another label in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a set of labels and sublabels like this:

```
user/
user/project 1/
user/project 1/money/
user/project 1/time/
user/project 1/etc/
```

I'd like to **copy** this label structure into a another label:

```
archive/user/
archive/user/project 1/
archive/user/project 1/money/
archive/user/project 1/time/
archive/user/project 1/etc/
```

I understand that with Gmail, the messages would have both sets of labels, but that's what I want to do for organizational reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to this with Thunderbird and the [Copy Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/copy-folder/) extension. After creating the top-level in Gmail, loading the Gmail account into Thunderbird and copying the folder will apply the new folder labels to the containing emails as expected.

Downloading the messages in a label as .MBOX files via Takeout is also an option.